# Why should I use object vs trait Dependencies and import it vs mixin to build definition?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been noticing people using the pattern with `object Dependencies` and doing `import Dependencies._` in `object build` in sbt as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Dependencies {
  // dependencies declared as vars
}

object build extends Build {
  // bring Dependencies' vars to scope
  import Dependencies._

  // project definitions
}
```

Quite recently I found another approach with a trait as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

trait Dependencies {
  // dependencies declared as vars
}

// bring Dependencies' vars to scope by with   
object build extends Build with Dependencies {
  // project definitions
}
```

I think that the trait approach gives me a better naming for the build object since it reads *object build is a Build with Dependencies inlined*.

What are the differences between the approaches (besides the perhaps better writing/reading of the object)?

I think the question might easily boil down to what the differences between objects and traits are in Scala, but since it's narrowed to sbt build definitions (that I think doesn't need so much expressiveness) I thought I'd ask here for build definition common patterns.

Comment: You canno inherit from `object` so it is impossible to build better abstractions and let program to decide at runtime which implementation to choose. `Trait` is a type while `object` is not. That's my opinion and it refers rather to `scala` in general than some pracitcal implications in `sbt`.

Comment: In first case, you're creating Dependencies as a singleton. State of an object will be shared between all its consumers. With traits each of consumers will get own, independent instance of a Dependencies.

Comment: I think in regards to sbt it's a scoping difference, if you use trait you can access the `val`s from `build.sbt` directly, as everything that's part of `Build` is visible in `build.sbt`. If you use `object` and import, then you will have to `import Dependencies._` to your `build.sbt` file or use qualified name.

Comment: From performance perspective better is use object. When you update trait - all classes mixing it have to be rebuilt. And in object you know that nobody override your setting (you can override methods in trait).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no semantic difference between the two. If you have to pick one, I'd prefer the `object Dependencies` variant because this one works better with `build.sbt` files.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Could you please chime in on what better means in this context?

Comment: better => it works.  You can't really override the trait easily in build.sbt, so it'd be hard to gain access to those members.